# Github Service Hooks: post-receive via PHP

Tags: php, git, github, nginx, git-post-receive

I'm having some issues deploying via service hook and I think it's a matter of permissions, but I'll state all the facts first.

Server:
Nginx w/ PHP-FPM on Arch Linux

Nginx is running as user http and has ownership of the directory to be updated by the script. I've also created an SSH key for HTTP and installed it on GitHub. Other commands seem to work just fine through the shell_exec, but I can't get a reset or a pull to complete and there's no output returned from either. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Hook script (PHP):

```
if ( isset($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]) )    { 
    $requestIP = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]; 
} else if ( isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]) )    { 
    $requestIP = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]; 
} else if ( isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"]) )    { 
    $requestIP = $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"]; 
}

// GitHub post-receive IPs
$validIPs = array(
    '207.97.227.253',
    '50.57.128.197',
    '180.171.174.178'.
    '50.57.231.61',
    '54.235.183.49',
    '54.235.183.23',
    '54.235.118.251',
    '54.235.120.57',
    '54.235.120.61',
    '54.235.120.62'
);

if(($payload = $_REQUEST['payload']) && in_array($validIps, $requestIP)) {
    $payload = json_decode($payload);
    $repository = $payload->repository->name;
    $docRoot = '/var/www/'.escapeshellcmd($repository);

    if(is_dir($docRoot)) {
        $command = 'cd '.$docRoot.' && git reset --hard HEAD && git pull';
        $output = shell_exec( $command );
        file_put_contents("hook.log", "$repository: $output\r\n", FILE_APPEND);     
    }
}
```

Comment: i could send `.; rm -rf $HOME` to your server as a false repo name and it would probably do some damage. Escape~

Comment: Yeah, I was just getting it work before locking it down. I'm going to limit access to github and escape the payload.

Comment: I edited the script to check for valid IPs, existence of variable and that the repository exists on my server. Also escaped the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the environment your commands run in.  It is possible git is not in the path that environment is using.

If this is the case, you could run git using it full pathname.

Comment: I can run git status without issue. It's only the resets and pulls that seem to fail.

Comment: can you find out what user id your command is running as ("id" command), what is the value of $HOME (echo $HOME), it may not read the key from the right place

Comment: id:
    uid=33(http) gid=33(http) groups=33(http)

$HOME:
    /srv/http

Both of which seem to be the expected values.

Comment: Have you tried running the git command as http user?  Get a shell (`sudo su - http` should get you an environment close to what php runs in) How did you do the initial clone in /var/www/...?  who owns the .git directory?

Comment: That was exactly it. my .git directory wasn't owned by http. Thanks!